# Smart way of assigning single member from vector A to vector B

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, lambda

This is a piece of code I'm currently using and I was wondering if there was a more elegant way of doing this in C++11 -

Essentially `vector_a` is copied to `vector_b`, then slightly modified, then `vector_b` is returned.

Vector elements are of class `Point` which is basically (leaving out constructors and a bunch of methods):

```
class Point {
    double   x,
             y,
             z;
};
```

Ideally I'd love to boil down the assignment of member `z` from `vector_a` to `vector_b` to something like a line or two but couldn't come up with an elegant way of doing it.

Any suggestions welcome!

```
auto localIter = vector_a.begin();
auto outIter = vector_b.begin();
while (localIter != vector_a.end() && outIter != vector_b.end())
{
    outIter->z = localIter->z;
    localIter++;
    outIter++;
}
```

Comment: Vectors have no member z. So could you show how the vectors are defined?

Comment: Vectors don't have, but element of vector does.

Comment: Depending on the vector element, you could solve this with just copy constructors. However, without knowing more information, it's impossible to say.

Comment: I don't immediately see a way to improve on this, but i would recommend always using the pre-increment operator. A post-increment requires a copy to be made, for complex types this might have a performance influence. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/59880/avoid-postfix-increment-operator

Comment: *then slightly modified* => which one is, `a` or `b` ? Would it be alright to assign & modify in one go ?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Ah - sorry. Info on elements in vector added. It's basically a point class. I was wondering in the larger context how to do just a partial copy of vector elements so left out the details..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partial copy is, actually, just a transformation of the elements (one of many), and therefore `std::transform` is a natural fit here.

Like many algorithms acting on multiple sequences, you have to be careful about the bounds of your containers; in this particular case, since `vector_b` just receives stuff, the easiest is to start empty and adjust its size as you go.

Thus, in the end, we get:

```
vector_b.clear();

std::transform(vector_a.begin(),
               vector_a.end(),
               std::back_inserter(vector_b),
               [](Elem const& a) { Elem b; b.z = a.z; return b; });
```

`transform` is perhaps the most generic algorithm in the Standard Library (it could imitate `copy` for example), so you should carefully consider whereas a more specialized algorithm exists before reaching for it. In this case, however, it just fits.

Comment: Thanks - it's not exactly what I've asked for but goes even beyond that as it combines copying and modifying the vector into a single step thus reducing the lines of code required. Great!

Answer (score 4):

You may use `transform()`.

```
std::transform (vector_a.begin(), vector_a.end(), vector_b.begin(), vector_a.begin(), [](Elem a, Elem b) { a->z = b->z; return a; });
```

Where `Elem` is a type of vector element.

Comment: Note: you are copying `Elem` here.

Comment: I assume that `sizeof(Elem) == 3*sizeof(int || float || double)`, that is not big enough to decrease performance noticeably. Plus, compiler can optimize some copyings out.

Comment: @ATV, Vlad's answer is better than mine. Accept it.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I think it washes out at the end, since `transform` will write to `vector_a`.

Answer (score 3):

As the vector has a random access iterator (using of `std::next` is effective) then I would write the code the following way

```
auto it = vector_a.begin();

std::for_each( vector_b.begin(), 
               std::next( vector_b.begin(), 
                          std::min( vector_a.size(), vector_b.size() ) ),
               [&it] ( Point &p ) { p.z = it++->z; } );
```

Comment: Cheers - good solution using standard libraries but, alas, not exactly concise. Well, we've got to work with what we've got. (..or were given)

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to do something a bit like this:

```
#include <vector>

struct info
{
    int z;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<info> a = {{1}, {2}, {3}};
    std::vector<info> b = {{4}, {5}};

    for(size_t i(0); i < a.size() && i < b.size(); ++i)
        b[i].z = a[i].z;
}
```